# Delete row in database table given one column value - which is a string

Tags: android

I have a table with column headings: | _id (long) | Name (String) | x (integer) | y (integer) |

I want to delete the row in the table that has Name myName.

```
// In onCreate
dbHelper = new DBAdapter(this);
dbHelper.open()

// Function in DBAdapter class
public boolean deleteTitleGivenName(String myName) 
{
    return dbHelper.delete(DATABASE_TABLE_2, KEY_NAME + "=" + myName, null) > 0;
}

// Function call in java code
dbHelper.deleteTitleGivenName(myName);  // this is where my code fails  

dbHelper.close();
```

Just as a note: myName is for sure in the database. Also, I can not use the ROWID since I am getting myName from a ListView.

I just started programming with Android and I have tried for days to solve this problem.
Is my WHERE clause correct (KEY_NAME + "=" + myName)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Sure, that works, although I would recommend

```
dbHelper.delete(DATABASE_TABLE_2, KEY_NAME + "=?", new String[] { myName })
```

for safety reasons. That way, you can have special characters without breaking your query. Did this not work?

Comment: wow. I tried your code and it works like a charm! Can you please explain the WHERE clause and the WhereArgs string[] ? I know the code works, but I would like to know how. 

By the way, thanks a lot!

Comment: "?" is basically a placeholder, so you can do something like "A=?, B<?, C>?". The next argument is a string array that contains all those placeholders, so in this example, you need to have exactly three arguments: new String[] { argumentForA, argumentForB, argumentForC }. The beauty is that those strings can have quotes, apostrophies, and what not, and it'll always work.That's also a good hacker protection, when people try to add SQL into names that are fed into queries.(Btw, not to be pushy - if my answer worked for you, please consider marking it 'best answer' so we both get a better score!)

Comment: Wow. thanks so much - really good explanation. I tried to Google my question but couldn't solve my problem for like 3 days! I just discovered this forum (so thanks for the 'best answer' tip :)

Thanks a lot, and I will be sure to post up more questions in the future.

Comment: for me this worked On _id column_key . i passed other columns here but the records does not delete . only if _ids are passed then a row is deleted.    how can i delete entire row from names column

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the value of the where clause in quotes...

```
KEY_NAME + "='" + myName + "'"
```

Also, it is bad practice (generally) to use a string-based WHERE clause. This is because if my name has an apostrophe in it, your app will not work. You should probably look for an alternative way to delete records from a database on Android.

Comment: cool. This code has also solved my problem. For future reference, can you please explain why this works?

And thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: SQL needs quotes (or apostrophies) for strings, just like most other languages, so it knows where the string ends and where the rest of the query continues. It's just like saying if (a.compare("My )string")) rather than (a.compare(My )String)).

Comment: Btw, string-based clauses aren't that bad - sometimes you just have to do them, and SQL is definitely a better choice than doing it in code. However, I would strongly suggest using "?" (see my answer) rather than putting it directly into the query - as explained above.

Answer (score 0):

depending on the complexity of your where condition, the "delete" method will not be the best solution.

for example, if you want to delete all records whose "_id" is in a second table, like you would write in transactSQL: "...WHERE _id IN (SELECT _id FROM..." then the best solution might be to use the ".execSQL()" method directly on your database.

```
myDatabase.execSQL("DELETE FROM myTable WHERE _id IN (SELECT _id FROM myOtherTable)");
```

or you could go real ugly and do something like:

```
int cursorRows = cursor.getCount();
String[] id2String = new String[cursorRows];
String id2StringUnique = "";
//for (int i=0;i<cursorRows;i++) {
int i=0;
for(cursor.moveToFirst(); !(cursor.isAfterLast()); cursor.moveToNext()){    
    id2String[i] = String.valueOf(cursor.getLong(index_ID));
    if (i==0) {
        id2StringUnique = "'"+id2String[i]+"'";
    } else {
        id2StringUnique += ",'"+id2String[i]+"'";
    }
    i++;
}
dbHelper.delete(DATABASE_TABLE_2, "_id IN (", id2StringUnique +")");
```

depending on number of items, you might have a problem with the length / size of your argument - besides it being diselegant to the extreme.

Answer (score 0):

just try this simple code

```
private void deleteItem()
 {
    try 
      {
      SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
      db.delete(TABLE_NAME, " title = 'haiyang'", null);
      setTitle("title");
    } catch (SQLException e) {

    }
```