# String[] whereArgs parameter of database method in android

Tags: android

```
delete(String table, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)

update(String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)
```

What is this `String[] whereArgs`? Is it connected with "?" (so called wild card)?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes, the `String[] whereArgs` contains the arguments to be appended to the `whereClause`.

For example, you want to make a delete query:

> delete from InfoTable where name = "ABC" and id = "23"

then the query should be:

```
delete("InfoTable", "name = ? AND id = ?" , new String[] {"ABC", "23"});
```

Comment: Thank you Frieza.Then If I want to delete all rows which "name" column values form A to C,  delete("InfoTable","name=? or name=? or name=?",String[]{"A","B","C"})  ?Any convenient way?

Comment: I'm not sure but the where clause `name in ?` with the whereArgs as `new String[]{"('A', 'B', 'C')"}` should work, though I haven't tried it

Comment: neither in ?-->{"(A,B,C)"} nor in ?-->{"('A','B','C')"} nor in (?)-->{"A,B,C"} works.The last won't get Exception,but wrong result.Well,write-all-in-whereClause wins,I think.Thank you Frieza.

Comment: ALso, there are security reasons for using ?s instead of write-all-in-whereClause. Details are [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3314257/1048087)

Comment: I know this is an old post, but consider the `IN` clause, `delete("InfoTable", "name IN (?)" , new String[] {"'A','B','C'"});` I think it should work like that.

Comment: @LuckyMe It won't work on the `Delete query`, tried and tested.