# What does this mean "id =?"

Tags: android

What does this line mean in my code `"id =?",new String[]{id}` .I have been trying find out on the internet but I can't seem to find an answer.

```
 public boolean updateData(String id,String name,String quantity,String category,String importance ) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_1, id);
    contentValues.put(COL_2, name);
    contentValues.put(COL_3, quantity);
    contentValues.put(COL_4, category);
    contentValues.put(COL_5, importance);
    Log.d("data","id="+id);
    Log.d("name",name);
    Log.d("quantity",quantity);
    Log.d("category",category);
    Log.d("importance",importance);

    db.update(Table_Name,contentValues,"id =?",new String[]{id});
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation on the Android API for `SQLiteDatabase.update`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String\[\] whereArgs parameter of database method in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560212/string-whereargs-parameter-of-database-method-in-android)

Comment: It's a placeholder for a bound parameter. It's positional, meaning that the first parameter passed will replace the first occurrence of `?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are in fact two distinct arguments to function SQLiteDatabase.update. The first ("id =?") is an update condition. This condition filters rows to update by a particular criteria, in this case by column id. The question mark is later subsituted by an argument in the next parameter, that defines an array of String objects that should be used for substitution of the placeholders (in this case question marks).