# whereArgs SQLite database delete

Tags: android, sqlite, delete-row

I'm trying to remove a couple of rows in a sqlite database programmatically for android and am wondering what the whereArgs are referring to in this documentation:

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d%29)

Can someone give me an example?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`whereArgs` are the values to the where clause. When you use the "?" (placeholder) in the second argument (`whereClause`), you've to provide the `whereArgs`. [See this post for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314176/delete-row-in-database-table-given-one-column-value-which-is-a-string).

Answer (score 3):

Put "`=?`" on the end of the second argument (whereClause), like this:

```
delete(CONTENT_URI, TEXT + "=?", new String [] { text } );
```

The `number of ?` is the number of arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Placeholders ? don't work (buggy) - so you need to construct the whereClause (selection) and send null arguments (selectionArgs)

e.g. To load a dynamic list from using user search text:

```
    mCustomerMenuList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.customer_menu_list);
    mSearchText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
    mSearchText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {          

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable t) {
               //Reload the query using the search text
               ManageMyCustomerMenuList();         
               mCustomerMenuList.setAdapter(mAdapter);          
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // Auto-generated method stub

        }
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            //  Auto-generated method stub

        }
        });
```

and in your `ManageMyCustomerMenuList()` query code place something like:

```
String s = mSearchText.getText().toString().toLowerCase();

String whereClause = Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE+" LIKE ?";
String whereArgs [] = new String[] {"%" +s+"%"};

mCustomerCursor = managedQuery(android.provider.Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, 
    new String[] {
        Browser.BookmarkColumns._ID,
        Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE, 
        Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL
    }, whereClause, whereArgs, mSqlLimit
);

mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row_layout_test, 
    mCustomerCursor, new String[] {
        Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE,
        Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL
    }, new int[] { 
        R.id.test_layout_view1, 
        R.id.test_layout_view2 
    }
);
```