# SQL placeholders ("?") don't work in SQLiteDatabae.update

Tags: android, sqlite

I have the following code in an `Update` method of a `ContentProvider` subclass:

When I use placeholders for the Where clause, my update does not work (`count` equals 0):

**Does not work:**

```
rowID = uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
whereStr = "?=?";
count = db.update(PathSQLTable.TABLE_NAME, values, whereStr, new String[]{PathSQLTable.ID_KEY,rowID});
```

But if I do the substituion manually, everything works fine.

**This works:**

```
rowID = uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
whereStr = PathSQLTable.ID_KEY + "=" + rowID;
count = db.update(PathSQLTable.TABLE_NAME, values, whereStr, null);
```

**My Question is**-- is there a bug in the placeholder logic (as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373380/whereargs-sqlite-database-delete)) or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it works only with the input parameters in the sql query, not with the columns name. So it should work if you try this:

```
rowID = uri.getPathSegments().get(1);
whereStr = PathSQLTable.ID_KEY + " = ?";
count = db.update(PathSQLTable.TABLE_NAME, values, whereStr,new String[]{rowID});
```

Comment: Interesting. Do you happen to know what gets sent as the SQL query in my "doesn't work" case? No errors are thrown by android, it just returns zero.

Comment: i only know that column names are provided without using `?`. Its the same as in C# for e.g. `select * from Customers where city = @City` where **@City** is provided via `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", "Stockholm");`. However, in your "doesn't work" query, i believe it translates `?` as for example **'ID_KEY'=6**, so ID_KEY is taken as a string value, not a column name, but its just my assumption :)

Comment: Ok, and that would explain why it's a valid query that returns zero records. Thanks.