# Android delete data from SQLite database

Tags: android, sql, database

I've created a SQLite Android dB in my app. I can add info to the dB without any problem. But I'm not able to delete anything from it.

This is my code:

```
        final SQLManager hon = new SQLManager(this);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

           long l = 3;
           hon.open();
           hon.deleteEntry(l);
           hon.close();
        }
                });
```

And here is the method "deleteEntry()":

```
       public void deleteEntry(long l) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, null, null);
       }
```

It was supposed to delete the whole dB, wasn't it? The button which makes the delete function when pressed is in the same view than the dB, is this a problem?

Comment: Do you want to delete the whole database? then need to use deleteDatabase. If you want to delete some rows http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314176/delete-row-in-database-table-given-one-column-value-which-is-a-string

Comment: I'd like to offer both posibilities in my app. I'll have a look on it.

Comment: I didn't find what i need yet. Answer would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the following code

```
ourDatabase.execSQL("delete from <TableName>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
// Will delete the whole database
public void DropDatabase(Context context) {
    context.deleteDatabase(ourDatabase.getPath());
}

// Will delete only the table
public void DropTable(String tableName) {
    ourDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE " + tableName);
}
```

Comment: No. The app runs well but nothing happens when i click the button

Answer (score 0):

Just use this method for deletion

```
public void deleteThirdMethod(String name){
    String query="delete from database_table where name = ?";
    String[] selections={name};
    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(query, selections);
}
```