# Is format String[] whereArgs correct in SQLiteDatabase.delete?

Tags: android, sqlite, outofrangeexception

Why this code:

```
String[] ids = {"5", "1", "3"};
db.delete(ACCOUNTS_TABLE, KEY_ROWID, ids);
```

return this exception?

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteBindOrColumnIndexOutOfRangeException: bind or column index out of range: handle 0x2069a88

Comment: Do you want to delete the Whole Row?

Comment: Possible duplicate see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314176/delete-row-in-database-table-given-one-column-value-which-is-a-string

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
dbHelper.delete(ACCOUNT_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=?", ids);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to delete single row.

```
String[] ids = {"5", "1", "3"};
for(int i=0; i<ids.length; i++)
{
    db.delete(ACCOUNTS_TABLE, ids[i], null);
}
```

Hope this Helps.