# can not delete from database

Tags: android, database

Can't solve the following. I have the list of items and names of those items saved in SQLite database. I use onContextItemSelected method to operate with items on list(add and delete). So far no problems to add to database new name and reflect new item in the list; but to remove makes me crazy. When I click to delete, item is deleted from the list but name could not be deleted from database.

Here is the code

```
       if (item.getItemId() == CM_DELETE_ID) {

                AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo acmi = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

                // delete item from list
                bazar.remove(acmi.position);

                // get clicked item id from list                    
                rowID = acmi.id;

                // open database          
                datasource.openToWrite();

                if (cursor != null) {

Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- Delete from mytable: ---");     

//delete from database
datasource.db.delete(DBHelper.TABLE, DBHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " + rowID, null);

Log.d(LOG_TAG, "deleted row = " + datasource.db.delete(DBHelper.TABLE, DBHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " + rowID, null));                                        

                } else {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Cursor is null");
                    cursor.close();
                }
                // close database
                datasource.close();

                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                return true;
```

Log says

```
 05:12:08.403   1131    example.CustomAdapter   DEBUG       row inserted, ID = 1
05:12:08.413    1131    example.CustomAdapter   DEBUG       ID = 1, name = A1
05:12:22.853    1131    example.CustomAdapter   DEBUG       row inserted, ID = 2
05:12:22.864    1131    example.CustomAdapter   DEBUG       ID = 1, name = A1
05:12:22.864    1131    example.CustomAdapter   DEBUG       ID = 2, name = A2
05:12:23.623    111 jp.co.omronsoft.openwnn DEBUG   dalvikvm    GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 20K, 44% free 3471K/6151K, external 3902K/3936K, paused 169ms
05:12:41.833    1131    example.CustomAdapter   DEBUG       --- Delete from mytable: ---
05:12:41.984    1131    example.CustomAdapter   DEBUG       deleted row count = 0
```

In onCreate I have dbReadAll method that lists all items I have and bazar.add(new Bazar(names, R.drawable.unread)); is my ArrayList

```
    void dbReadAll() {

    bazar.add(new Bazar(names, R.drawable.unread));

    // подключаемся к базе данных для чтения данных
    datasource.openToRead();

    // получаем значение курсора        
    cursor = datasource.queryAll();

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        nameColIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN);

        do {

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "ID = " + cursor.getInt(idColIndex) + ", name = " + cursor.getString(nameColIndex));

            names = cursor.getString(nameColIndex);

            bazar.add(new Bazar(names, R.drawable.unread));

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());

    } else {
        cursor.close();
        datasource.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you are mapping the row id wrong, rowid may not equal acmi.id .

So what you can do is get row id from cursor

```
cursor.movetoPosition(acme.id);    
rowid = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_ID))
```

Comment: Let me see. I need some time. Your suggestion is very reasonable. That is what I thought. Did not know how to operate cursor in this situation.

Comment: now when I add new postion to the list and accordingly new name to database and want delete what I have entered the following error occures

Comment: 06:33:35.404 1424 example.CustomAdapter ERROR AndroidRuntime FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06:33:35.404 1424 example.CustomAdapter ERROR AndroidRuntime android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 requested, with a size of 2

Comment: another try to add and then delete and Log says

Comment: 06:41:59.193 1461 example.CustomAdapter ERROR AndroidRuntime FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06:41:59.193 1461 example.CustomAdapter ERROR AndroidRuntime java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery (mSql = SELECT * FROM mytable)

Comment: 07:00:01.063 1541 example.CustomAdapter ERROR AndroidRuntime FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07:00:01.063 1541 example.CustomAdapter ERROR AndroidRuntime android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 requested, with a size of 3

Comment: it gives me errors again and again when I try to delete. What it could be.

Comment: when you got illegalstate exception, you had closed the cursor. But indexoutofboundsException, do you have a header or something in listview

Comment: That is right. Thank you very much for responce. I have first position already filled with one item. Because without it ContextItemSelected could not work. Right now I am thinking how to go around. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Looking forward to hear from you since it is first app I am developing on my own.

Comment: You can see what I have now and it works except for the last position add. When I have in the list 4 positions, one already filled item and three others added, and I want to delete last one (4th in the list and 3rd added) I've got the following error: 08:31:31.323 2267 example.CustomAdapter ERROR AndroidRuntime android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 requested, with a size of 3

Comment: if you know that the first item is always filled, you could just use cursor.movetoPosition(acme.id -1);

Comment: Let me try this one. Man, don't go away. Don't leave me now.

Comment: 08:52:38.894 2340 example.CustomAdapter ERROR AndroidRuntime android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 2

Comment: how have you filled the first item? is it from cursor itself? I did not get why it was failing in contextItemSelected.

Comment: This one when I try to delete filled item. Sorry, but what is the possible solution. If there is no way around with cursor probably I shoud remove it from list when first database item is added? But how to do this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18158/discussion-between-nandeesh-and-user1706819)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
//delete from database
datasource.db.delete(DBHelper.TABLE, DBHelper.COLUMN_ID + "=?", new String[]{Long.toString(rowID)});
```

It seems delete statement uses pre prepared queries For more see [this sof question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314176/delete-row-in-database-table-given-one-column-value-which-is-a-string)

**UPDATE** changed `rowId` to `Long.toString(rowId)` We needed to enter a string in the string array

Comment: I assume that when I delete item from the list id position of other items is changing and next time when I get rowID from the list, database deletes its own id holder but not the one from the list.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. But as far as I understand, you need to remove from the list and database separately.

Comment: Give me some time please to run everything and check it up.

Comment: 05:55:02.583 1349 example.CustomAdapter ERROR AndroidRuntime FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05:55:02.583 1349 example.CustomAdapter ERROR AndroidRuntime android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "[Ljava.lang.String;@4052b120": , while compiling: DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id = [Ljava.lang.String;@4052b120

Comment: What is the datatype of `rowId`

Comment: It is long and what I mean when I receive rowId let say 0 and give it to database delete, it will delete data stored under own id=0. That is what I afraid of.

Comment: At the same time previous delete just moved current position up. May be I am wrong please let me know.

Comment: Yes you are right. It will. In that case, what I generally do is, take id of each entry in database, and put it in each entry in the list in a textview whose visibility cirteria is 'View.GONE'. On any row selected, I retrieve this id and pass it along to delete/update statements. Also, I have made slight changes in the code above. PLease check it out

Comment: Can you provide me with sample code on suggestion. I am a new one and afraid will not be able to develop it on my own.

Comment: Is the problem to delete solved? Do you understand the approach i am talking about?

Comment: I do understand approach but I dont have enough experience to make it in code. Do you have any samples to share or references where I can find it. Thank you.

Comment: I am away from my development machine right now. I do not have anything to share right now. However, you may try it out tell where the problem is. Just bind the id of the database table to one of the hidden textviews in each row, on select get this id and then delete it.

Comment: I think better approach will be to use database cursor but anyway thank you for helping out.